# "Can't find string terminator '' before EOF when running Perl script on MacOSX?

Tags: macos, perl

I am getting the error

```
Can't find string terminator '"' anywhere before EOF
```

when running the following script on Mac OSX.   Note that this script was copied directly from a Mac forum...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Hi there!\n”
```

Comment: You're closing the string incorrectly. You used `”` instead of `"`.

Comment: Note that if you're going to continue encode your source code using UTF-8, you will need to add `use utf8;`.

Answer (score 2):

The double-quoted string literal starting at the seventh position of the second line is not terminated because you used `”` instead of `"` when you attempted to end the literal.

Replace

```
print "Hi there!\n”
```

with

```
print "Hi there!\n"
```